# Convert NSString into byte array iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios4

Hi I want to convert the NSString into Byte array.

if I have string like "Hello" then it convert into byte like this {65,23,56,56,56}.

thanks

Comment: I guess he wants the ASCII values, although those would be pretty wrong. I assume he just chose some random values. <g>

Comment: yes I put the random number not exact number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `-[NSString UTF8String]` which returns `const char*`. Read [the reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-CJBHCCED).

A general tip: if you want to find if a class has a method which does something, look up the official reference! I mean, on the web, there's not only Stack Overflow, but the API provider's (i.e. Apple's or Microsoft's) official documentations!

Comment: [NSString UTF8String] doesn't really give you a clue it returns pointer to a char. Than you have to read all the API methods to find something you need and this is just for one class. The Foundation frameworks has like tons of classes, this is not doable, so yes, SO or google is a tool for help. If you also develop on other frameworks in a short amount o time, you simply have no time to study all the APIs. Also, the APIs changes over time, so just asks and if you don't get response, do the research yourself, otherwise SHARE KNOWLEDGE.

Answer (score 5):

```
NSData *bytes = [test dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: hey it return hexa value and I try to get bytes using  this  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSUInteger len = [data length];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);    but It gives me a special character not in digits

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html):

"Gets a given range of characters as bytes in a specified encoding."

```
- (BOOL)getBytes:(void *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)maxBufferCount usedLength:(NSUInteger *)usedBufferCount encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding options:(NSStringEncodingConversionOptions)options range:(NSRange)range remainingRange:(NSRangePointer)leftover
```