# How to convert Base64 encoded NSString into Byte Array(Java) in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, character-encoding, arrays

I have an Image that is converted into NSData and which in-turn is converted into base64 encoded NSString. Now i have a service that accepts this base64 encoded string in only Byte Array(Java Supported). I tried different options but i am not able to convert the encoded string into Byte Array type. Can someone please help me on how to convert the encoded string into Byte Array(Java supported)?

Below is my answer for this. I came to know that the easiest way is to convert the image data into byte array directly without base64encoding the data.

Comment: This answer will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700431/iosconvert-string-to-hexadecimal-array/27700913#27700913

Answer (score 0):

```
NSError* error;
NSString* str=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"black-circle" ofType:@"png"];
NSData* data=  [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:str options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

NSInteger length=[data length];
const char* dataBytes=[data bytes];
```

Now you can traverse each byte using dataBytes pointer. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: I already have a NSString with me which is converted from NSData and i want it to be converted into unsigned char (Byte Array) type. In the example you have shared you are again converting the string into NSData. You didnt get my question. All i wanted is to convert an NSString into Byte Array. Please let me know if you havent understood my question.

Comment: why you dont just convert directly from NSData to bytes array. And if you only want to go this way then    you can again convert back from NSdata to base 64 string as :                                                             NSString *base64Encoded = @"some base64 string";
 NSData *nsdataFromBase64String = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64Encoded options:0];

Comment: No. I don't need it in the way you have mentioned. I need the NSString to be converted to Byte Array that is supported in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out :
 Use`-[NSString UTF8String]` which returns `const char*`.

or this link will help you : 
[Convert NSString into byte array iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725451/convert-nsstring-into-byte-array-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

We can get the NSdata from the NSStirng and then convert NSData into Byte Array. The easier way is to convert the captured image data into Byte Array using uint8_t. Below is the code snippet that does the trick.

**NSData to Byte Array:-**

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageCaptured);

    uint8_t byteArray[[data length]];

    [data getBytes:&byteArray];

    NSMutableString *byteArrayString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(byteArray); i++) {

        [byteArrayString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,",byteArray[i]]];

    }

    // Removing last extra comma
    [byteArrayString deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([byteArrayString length]-1, 1)];
```